# SonarLint IDEA plugin not in sync even in Connected Mode

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, intellij-plugin, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I am using SonarLint for Intellij 2.0, It's connected to my own SonarQube server v5.4 with no issues reported by the plugin when going into Connected Mode.

It seems not to be in sync with my server rules.  Found those mentioned in [the doc for Java](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/rules/index.html#version=2.0.1&ruleId=S1166&tags=error-handling&language=Java) but they also seemed not to be all.  I wonder if these java rule list are used only when it's not connected to any server only.

Does it have a restriction on what rules to use or synchronize when using a remote server? Am I missing any step?

Is in any case this issue related? https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-57

I am running:
Intellij 15.0.2 build #IU-143.1184
JRE 1.8.0_40-release-b105 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o 
SonarLint for Intellij 2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rules listed in SonarLint website are indeed the one enabled when you are **not** connected.
- When you are connected the rules are the one **enabled** in the quality profile of the associated project.

To investigate your issue please open a thread in SonarLint Google group.